# Static cell with TextField - connect class property to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I want to be able to have a TextField in my static cells so I'm using the `StringInputTableViewCell` class from this demo: https://github.com/wannabegeek/PickerTableViewCell/tree/master/PickerCellDemo

I'm using storyboards and in my storyboard I got 2 cells that use the StringInputTableViewCell class. As you can see there is a `UITextField` property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *textField;
```

in `StringInputTableViewCell.h`. On storyboards in `MyViewController` I can connect the label, etc with a property but I cannot connect the TextField since its added in code and the TextField isn't on my storyboard. So my question is how do I get that property in `MyViewController` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your "`StringInputTableViewCell`" a property within your "`MyViewController`", or if you're trying to populate it during "`cellForRowAtIndexPath`", you can get get access to it through an identifier or a tag.

Once you have a pointer to the "`StringInputTableViewCell`" object that's being displayed in your table, you can then access the "`textField`" property of it in your code directly.

Something like:

```
StringInputTableViewCell * stringInputCell = (StringInputTableViewCell *) cell;
if(stringInputCell)
{
    stringInputCell.textField.text = @"Surprise, I can put text in here!";
}
```

Comment: So make a property in MyViewController and then connect this property to the cell?

Comment: Are you using this StringInputTableViewCell in a table or?

Comment: I got a Table View with 2 table view cells

Comment: I tried to add an outlet property in MyViewController like this: @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet StringInputTableViewCell *Cell; however I cannot connect this with the storyboard cell

Comment: Look at the PickerCellDemo project that you pointed us to and see how they do this: add a prototype cell to the table view in your storyboard and then set the custom type for that prototype cell to "`StringInputTableViewCell`". You can set an outlet on that prototype cell, or you can catch it being returned with "`cellForRowAtIndexPath`".

Comment: I had forgotten to put the add the custom class to the cell, silly me. Thanks!